# XSLT shortcut for conditional statements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a ton of this in a large stylesheet and it's making the stylesheet become really cumbersome:

```
<xsl:when test="Field_Goal_Stats/Field_Goal_Total/FGTtl_Attempted">
               "attempted": <xsl:value-of select="number(Field_Goal_Stats/Field_Goal_Total/FGTtl_Attempted)" />,</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>
               "attempted": 0,</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is straight forward. I'm trying to grab the `number()` from a respective XPath. If that fails, normally with NaN, because the field doesn't exist or the field doesn't contain a value that's appropriate for `number()`, I set it to zero.

Is there anyway to either do this in 1 line or somehow create a re-usable component that I can apply against a ton of other XPath nodes I'm running this code against? Seems wrong to keep doing the whole choose/otherwise pattern in so many parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `xsl:call-template` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="myTestField" select="Field_Goal_Stats/Field_Goal_Total/FGTtl_Attempted" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="myTestField" select="Field_Goal_Stats/Field_Goal_Total/FGTtl_AttemptedSecondField" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="myTemplate">
        <xsl:param name="myTestField" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$myTestField">
                "attempted": <xsl:value-of select="number($myTestField)" />,
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                "attempted": 0,
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need to repair the `test=""` as an empty string is not a valid XPath address.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(Field_Goal_Stats/Field_Goal_Total/FGTtl_Attempted,0)[1]"/>
```

When the value exists, you get it ... when the value doesn't exist, the first value of the resulting sequence is `0`.

This is not available in XSLT 1.0.